# Is there a way to join in linq on 1 value being more than another with the < operator?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get two rows from a table, in linq. One with a matching Id and one with the next record based on a sequence column in the table.

I tried with something like the following code, but the < operator gives me an error.

```
var result = from t1 in db.Table1
             join t2 in db.Table1
             on t1.Sequence < t2.Sequence
             where t1.Id == Id
             orderby t2.Sequence
             select new { t1, t2 };
```

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: Expected contextual keyword 'equals'

Comment: I think that is something like this `where t1.Id.Equals(Id)`

Comment: in his case "Equals" would give back twice the same row.
what he wants is the next row